# A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type xxx

Tags: flutter, dart

I just upgraded to flutter 2.0. Now I get this error

```
  case ABC.ROUTE:
            final AsssetTrasferArguments args = settings.arguments;
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => ProxyProvider<Repo, AssetBloc>(
                update: (context, repository, assetBloc) =>
                    AssetBloc(repository: repository),
                dispose: (context, assetBloc) => assetBloc.dispose(),
                child: ABC(args),
              ),
            );
            break;
```

**Error**

```
A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AsssetTrasferArguments'.Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'AsssetTrasferArguments'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
final args = settings.arguments;
```

you don't have to specify the type

Comment: Thanks. I have  one more question
Ex I declared 100 list `var list = List<int>();`

Comment: After upgrade, I need change 100 list to `var list = <int>[]` one by one? or can change all in one time?

Comment: change them manual. You can search in all the project code and replace every `List<int>()` with `<int>[]`

Answer (score 0):

If 'AsssetTrasferArguments' is a class you created, then I think it's preferable if you made a constructor that takes an Object and sets its parameters to the attributes of the class.

For example:
If you have, in your class, the following attributes

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

And you want to set their values using an array, you better make a constructor that does something like:

```
myclass.a = array[0];
myclass.b = array[1];
myclass.c = array[2];
```

Hope this helped.